# Pipe envsubst output to hive

Tags: linux, bash, hive

Working with Hive 0.13.0, I would like to evaluate variables against a template and then immediately execute the resulting Hive code (avoiding a temporary intermediate file is preferable).

Here is a (non-working) example of what I'd like to do:

**template.hql**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${TABLE};
```

In the shell:

```
export TABLE=DEFAULT.FOOTABLE
envsubst < template.hql | hive
```

Is there a particular reason this does not work, and is there a proper way to achieve it?

Comment: Perhaps because your template has `$TABLE` while your environment variable is `$TABLES` (plural)?

Comment: @bishop, nope sorry, that was just a typo in the toy example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The substitution works as expected:

```
$ cat template.hql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ${TABLE};
$ export TABLE=DEFAULT.FOOTABLE
$ envsubst < template.hql
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DEFAULT.FOOTABLE;
```

So I suspect `hive` does not read queries from the standard in. I see from [an online manual](http://hadooptutorial.info/hive-cli-commands/) that it supports the `-f` parameter, so you can create the file manually:

```
TMPFILE=$(mktemp)
envsubst < template.hql > $TMPFILE
hive -f $TMPFILE
rm $TMPFILE
```

If you're on a newish version of bash, you can avoid an intermediate file:

```
hive -f <( envsubst < template.hql )
```

I'm not sure, but also check if `hive -f -` might read from stdin.